# How to prove using AM-GM $ \frac{4}{abcd} \ge \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{d} + \frac{d}{a} $

Tags: contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a, b, c$ and $d$ be positive numbers such that $a+b+c+d =4$, prove that

$$ \frac{4}{abcd}  \ge  \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{d} + \frac{d}{a} $$

I am supposed to prove my using AM-GM, so I tried

$$ a + b+ c+ d \ge 4(abcd)^{1/4} $$
$$ 1 \ge abcd$$

also by AM GM 
$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{d} + \frac{d}{a} \ge 4 $$
The only way I get the desired result is by dividing the first inequality by second and cross multiplying, but two inequalities can't be divided without sign change.

Comment: I'm assuming $a, b, c, d$ are positive, not just non-negative!